# Migrating UA Views approach to the new Google Analytics (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to figure out the optimal setup for the client's use case with GA4.

Some background:

- It's an online media brand with multiple sub-sites (subdomains), with one sub-site having multiple editions (editions are like content verticals, e.g. "Cooking", "Sports", "Tech"...)
- All sub-sites are hosted under a single domain as subdomains - `events.example.com`, `jobs.example.com`, etc...
- All editions are part of a single subdomain - `news.example.com`
- Client looks at and treats all editions as separate websites, so for them "Jobs" (*entire subdomain*) and "Sports" (*some of the pages of a single subsite*) are encapsulated in terms of reporting and tracking, even though one is a subdomain-scoped website and another - an edition - a collection of pages from a single `news.example.com` website.

We had the following setup with UA:

- We had a single property for all sub-sites and editions, single tracking code used across all subdomains.
- We had a single "global" View in this property for unfiltered data from all sub-sites and editions.
- Additionally, we had one View per sub-site, which included only the traffic coming to a given sub-domain (filtered through [View filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en)).
- And finally, we had one View per edition, which includes only the traffic that has the custom dimension `edition` set to the given edition (again, filtered through View filters).

This gave the Client clean and clear Views for everything - for every sub-site and for every edition of that single news-sub-site. They could see the real-time reports for each View (for each subsite/edition) and browse the reports easily within the View.

I'm trying to replicate the same with GA4 but since the Views are gone I'm having trouble coming up with the right approach here.

Here are some thoughts:

- We DO have all the dimensions needed for this in GA4 - *Hostname* can be used to target sub-sites with a subdomain and we also have our custom *Edition* dimension. But applying these filters manually for every report is tedious.
- Having separate Data Sources for every sub-site and edition gives nothing, since Data Source is not a dimension.
- There is also an option to create separate GA4 properties for all the sub-sites and editions, and use the same tag fired everywhere to collect data, but GA4 Property's [Data Filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13296761?hl=en) are only useful for filtering OUT developer or internal traffic.
- Another option is to have a single property for everything and manually build custom reports for all sub-sites and editions, applying appropriate filters to those reports. But this approach is (1) too much work and most importantly (2) won't give the client ability to view real-time reports for each sub-site or edition.
- And finally, there is an option to have separate GA4 properties for all the sub-sites and editions, with separate tags firing for each of them, plus having a "global" GA4 property with its own tag, firing IN ADDITION to the "specific" property tags. This approach will give us separate properties (pre-made reports) for every sub-site or edition + separate real-time report for every sub-site or edition + additional "global" property with all the data aggregated. But... this feels hacky and over-engineered.

So, how would you approach this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.